# Find the coordinates of the point С on a line passing through the point A and B, if:

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Find the coordinates of the point С on a line passing through the point A and B, if:

$$A(2;-3;1)$$
$$B(-2;2;-4) $$
$$|AC|:|AB|=4:5$$

What is given is the ratio? .. I can not imagine (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given the points A=(2,-3,1) and B = (-2,2,-4).

The line segment AB can be constructed from the points A and B component-wise:
$AB = (b_1-a_1,b_2-a_2,b_3-a_3) = (-2-2,2-(-3),-4-1) \rightarrow AB= (-4,5,-5)$
The magnitude/norm/length of the line segment S is |S| and is defined as:
$|S| = \sqrt{s_1^2+s_2^2+s_3^2} $

Using the above, $|AB| = \sqrt{(-4)^2+5^2+(-5)^2} =\sqrt{16+25+25}\implies |AB| = \sqrt{66}$

We are given the information that |AC|:|AB| = 4:5. This means that $|AC|\over|AB|$=$4\over5$.

Knowing that |AB|=$\sqrt{66}$, we can solve for |AC|: $|AC|$ = $4|AB|\over5$=$4\sqrt{66}\over5$

This means that AC is a line segment that starts at A and ends at C with a distance of $4\sqrt{66}\over5$, which corresponds to 4 fifths of the length of line segment AB.

Comment: Wow thanks!!! And what the answer would be?

Comment: What should I do?